# Angular ng-grid click event not triggered

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-click

In the below plunkr, there is a ng-grid with some records. Each row in a ng-grid has a remove button, on clicking that button listener is not getting called.

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/ffEfZP8ygV1pMD8PGQgV?p=preview][1]
```

Please tell why this listener is not called on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem if with you using the variable $index in your template.
Try like this:

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.removeRow(row)"
```

And then, in your removeRow function, you are now receiving the row object. Just find it in your Data Object and delete it.

```
var index = $scope.myData.indexOf(row.entity);
$scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. but I have a clarification on this, why `ng-click="removeRow(grid.appScope.removeRow(row))"` works while `ng-click="removeRow()"` (without parameters) doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I guess is because the Grid creates a new Scope for it self. So, the outside RemoveRow is not on your application $scope, but in your Grid-Scope. And you use the Grid-Scope.removeRow to call the AppScope.removeRow. And since they are in diferent Scopes you need to pass parameters for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$scope.apply();` at the end of `AddToGrid` method as below

```
  $scope.addToGrid = function() {

    $scope.myData.push({
      "firstName": $scope.firstName,
      "lastName": $scope.lastName,
      "company": $scope.company,
      "employed": $scope.employed
    });
    $scope.firstName = '';
    $scope.lastName = '';
    $scope.company = '';
    $scope.employed = false;

    $scope.apply();

  }
```

Comment: Why should I add `$scope.apply()` in `addToGrid` function?

Comment: @Vimal Your method is called already, add `alert(1)` at beginning of method and it's called, and record is added to myData. So the only problem is the changes in not reflected on UI, by $scope.apply() you force angular to rebind the values